# FileSystemNotFoundException when accessing resources inside a Docker container

Tags: java, docker

I have an application that runs inside a Docker container. The application has a dependency to a library called `mylibrary`. The library gets the path to a folder called `/schemas` within the classpath as follows.

```
URL resource= getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("schemas");
Path path = Paths.get(resource.toURI());
```

Running the application results in a `FileSystemNotFoundException` caused by `Paths.get()`. I was able to fix this by creating a `FileSystem` object using `FileSystem.getDefault()` and using this object to get the path.

Running the code locally on my linux machine, I get a path like `/data/code/mylibrary/target/classes/schemas/`. However, running the my application via Docker it gives me something `file:/root/.m2/repository/de/monticore/lang/monticar/mylibrary/0.4.10-SNAPSHOT/mylibrary-0.4.10-SNAPSHOT.jar!/schemas`. Using the latter, my code throws `FileNotFoundExceptions`.

What is wrong here?

Hint: I have to provide the path to another library, which does some schema validation. Therefore, I need the path.